# CSS - Detect if element is grabbed/dragged/moved

Tags: html, css

I know I can change the cursor on hover, but is it possible to detect mouse grabs?

E.g. Try to drag the items in the following example, my goal is to change the cursor to `cursor: move` if an element is moved.

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>jQuery UI Sortable - Connect lists</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
  <style>
  #sortable {
    border: 1px solid #eee;
    width: 142px;
    min-height: 20px;
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 5px 0 0 0;
    float: left;
    margin-right: 10px;
  }
  #sortable li {
    margin: 0 5px 5px 5px;
    padding: 5px;
    font-size: 1.2em;
    width: 120px;
  }
  #sortable li:hover {
    cursor: pointer;
  }
   
  #sortable li:mousedrag {
    cursor: move;
  }
  </style>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <script>
  $( function() {
  
    $( "#sortable" ).sortable({
        connectWith: ".connectedSortable"
    }).disableSelection();
    
  });
  </script>
</head>
<body>
 
  <ul id="sortable" class="connectedSortable">
    <li class="ui-state-default" value="1">Item 1</li>
    <li class="ui-state-default" value="2">Item 2</li>
    <li class="ui-state-default" value="3">Item 3</li>
    <li class="ui-state-default" value="4">Item 4</li>
    <li class="ui-state-default" value="5">Item 5</li>
  </ul>
  
  <button id="save">Save</button>
 
</body>
</html>
```

I search for something like this:

```
  #sortable li:mousedrag {
    cursor: move;
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

jQuery UI add `.ui-sortable-helper` class to the item you are dragging.
See below snippet.

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>jQuery UI Sortable - Connect lists</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
  <style>
  #sortable {
    border: 1px solid #eee;
    width: 142px;
    min-height: 20px;
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 5px 0 0 0;
    float: left;
    margin-right: 10px;
  }
  #sortable li {
    margin: 0 5px 5px 5px;
    padding: 5px;
    font-size: 1.2em;
    width: 120px;
  }
  #sortable li:hover {
    cursor: pointer;
  }
   
  #sortable li:mousedrag {
    cursor: move;
  }
  #sortable li.ui-sortable-helper{
    cursor: move;
}
  </style>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <script>
  $( function() {
  
    $( "#sortable" ).sortable({
        connectWith: ".connectedSortable"
    }).disableSelection();
    
  });
  </script>
</head>
<body>
 
  <ul id="sortable" class="connectedSortable">
    <li class="ui-state-default" value="1">Item 1</li>
    <li class="ui-state-default" value="2">Item 2</li>
    <li class="ui-state-default" value="3">Item 3</li>
    <li class="ui-state-default" value="4">Item 4</li>
    <li class="ui-state-default" value="5">Item 5</li>
  </ul>
  
  <button id="save">Save</button>
 
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
#sortable li.ui-sortable-helper {
   cursor: move;
}
```

Here's a working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/mWYEH/

Answer (score 0):

I just had to change

```
$( "#sortable" ).sortable({
    connectWith: ".connectedSortable"
}).disableSelection();
```

to this:

```
$( "#sortable" ).sortable({
    cursor: 'move',
    connectWith: ".connectedSortable"
}).disableSelection();
```